# Process never ends when using 'process.stdin.once'

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, user-input, stdin

In my node script, I am waiting for the user to press enter at some point:

```
console.log("Press enter to continue...");
await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    process.stdin.once("data", function(data) {
        resolve();
    });
});
```

The script runs fine, and continues only after the user has pressed enter.

But at the end of the execution, the process does not terminate.

Instead, it seems to be just pending for user input (i.e., a newline is printed every time I press enter).

I'm pretty sure that the problem is related to `process.stdin.once`, and not to how I use the `Promise` in order to force synchronous execution.

I have several places in my script where I have to wait for the user to press enter, so adding `process.stdin.end()` before resolving the promise is out of the question here (it means that waiting for the user to press enter will work only once).

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: That cannot be all of your code, as `await` can only be use inside an `async` function.

Comment: @Pointy: Of course it's not all of my code. I've pretty much stated that explicitly ("my script does this and that..."). And yes - this snippet is indeed invoked from an `async` function.

Comment: OK well one never knows around here what might be lurking in unposted code. That said, the given answer is correct, though idiomatically in UNIX/Linux C code you'd probably just explicitly `exit()` or fall out of the `main` function (which I realize doesn't exist in Node programs).

Comment: @Pointy: Technically, since I do know where my script starts and ends looking past all the asynchronous calls), I just ended up adding `process.stdin.resume()` at the beginning and `process.stdin.pause()` at the end. All the rest remained the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is happening because as long as your stdin stream is *open*, node assumes you might be waiting for more data. The stream is automatically opened after you read from it in any way. An easy way to inform node you no longer want more input is to call `pause()`. Here's a simple example:

```
async function example() {
    console.log("Step 1");
    await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        process.stdin.once("data", function(data) {
            resolve();
        });
    });

    console.log("Step 2");
    await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        process.stdin.once("data", function(data) {
            resolve();
        });
    });

    // more steps...
}

example().then(() => {
    console.log("Done");
    process.stdin.pause();
});
```

Comment: So can I just call `process.stdin.pause()` before `resolve()`?

Comment: Sort of - if you do that, you have to make sure you also `resume()` before you attempt to gather user input again.  It's safe to call `resume()` on already-resumed stream, and same for `pause()`, so if you want to wrap up the "wait for user input" logic into a little helper function, you should first call `resume()`, then set up your `once` handler, and then `pause()` before returning.