# Using child_process.spawn() to open VIM on raw mode causes it to freeze

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, vim, iterm

Mind the following script:

```
const child_process = require('child_process');

process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
process.stdin.on("data", (data) => {});

var child = child_process.spawn("vim", ["README.md"], {stdio: "inherit"});
child.on("exit", (e, code) => {
  process.exit();
});
```

It sets raw mode and then opens `README.md` on `vim`. After typing for a few seconds, VIM completely stops responding. Pressing keys do nothing and the only way to recover is to close the tab. This problem is solved by removing the `on("data")` callback. I'm using iTerm on macOS Catalina, node version `v13.10.1`. Is this script wrong, or is this a bug on Node.js, VIM or perhaps iTerm?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be caused when `process.stdin.on("data")` is active, which [causes Node.js to hang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54182732/process-never-ends-when-using-process-stdin-once) waiting for input. This can be solved by using `process.stdin.pause` before spawning the child process, and then using `process.stdin.resume` to continue listening inside `child.on("exit")`.

Comment: Remove on("data") callback.

Comment: @LukasC I obviously need on("data") for other things, this is just a minimal reproduction of the problem.